# Splitting pieces of a mesh into a new object

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've just made a set of armor by using a male body mesh model I downloaded and selecting certain faces from the model and duplicating them to create viable armor pieces.

Since the pieces are just duplicated from the same mesh male model, then it's still part of the same object.

How do I separate the armor piece from the model to make the pieces separate?

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Select the object.

Enter edit mode (press <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>)

Press <kbd>P</kbd>*> Selection* to [separate](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/separate.html) the selection into a new object:

[image]

[image]

From the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/separate.html):

> ### Options

*Selected*
This option separates the selection to a new object.

> *By Loose Parts*
> Separates the mesh in its unconnected parts.
> *By Material*
> Creates separate mesh objects for each material.

Note that if there are no disconnected parts of the mesh besides the armor, using the *By Loose Parts* option might be faster.

Also note that you can select linked geometry by:

- Pressing <kbd>L</kbd> with your mouse over geometry will select all geometry connected to the element below your cursor.
- Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> will select all geometry connected to any selected element(s).

To access the option from a menu use *Mesh* > *Separate*

[image]

Comment: Confusingly, it only exists in: Mesh > Vertices ... even if you're not working with vertices.