# Separating parts of an object

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to ungroup an imported Wavefront(.obj) object? I have created the object in EasyToy and would like to finish it with Blender due to it's better functionality.

The object looks like this:

[image]

But I can't select just for example an ear or eyeball. So my question is: is it possible to do this or do I have to select the single parts by selecting faces, edges etc.?

Comment: What does "grouped" mean exactly? Is there a single object with multiple vertex groups? Can the parts be told apart by material?

Comment: Greate, thank you. That worked just perfect.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object

Answer (score 3):

In **Edit Mode** unselect all by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>.

Select a vertex from one part of the mesh and press <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> to **select linked**.

Then you can press <kbd>P</kbd> to **separate** that part of the mesh into a new object, you then have the option to separate the elements by selection, material or loose parts.