# How to apply material selectively on a single object for a downloaded 3d model

Tags: materials, import, linked-data

Hi I am new to blender and am trying my hands on creating a house from different 3d models imported from freely available websites.

So I downloaded a few study rooms and bedrooms from http://tf3dm.com/. However now when I try to apply texture specifically to (say) a bedsheet, it is commonly applied to all the walls and the floors and a lot of furniture around.

How do I unlink all these objects and apply materials specifically to individual components of the house?

Comment: No, this is not my problem. I found a solution to my problem [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2856/18957). The issue was the materials were linked to the data. When I selected _object_ the issue was sorted. However do I have to unlink all the objects individually? Is there any short cut like `Ctrl + A` for `select all` in blender?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16445/separating-parts-of-an-object/16452#16452