# Is there an effective way to cut out a portion of a model without destroying it's topology?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, sculpting, topology

Im making a 3d print object for the dishonored mask. A big part of the face of the mask is made look like the metal casting for the mask failed, and a plate was hammered into the face. I have sculpted the face WHOLE but I need a way to get that bit out of the model. I tried using boolean but the topology went horrible, and I was not able to sculpt the model around the cut edges.

Is there a more effective way to do this?

Plate is hammered into the right face (left face from the wearers view)
[image: Mask shown]

This is how I originally intended on doing this, copied the plate (I have already made the model) and made it thicker, and applied boolean modifier.
[image: Im not good at describing]

This is the wound i got from apllying the boolean modifier. (after inflating, it was flat right after booling, but this shows how bad the topology got.)
[image: Wound from boolean]

Here is the face
[image]
And the plate
[image]
Also this is the first time I model, so please don't give super complicated answers, and if they are, please explain well.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: possibly a duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object

Comment: this is a very tough project for a first try something easier to start with, cause the answers you'll see are gonna be pretty hard-core.