# Is it possible/how to separate several "objects" imported from an stl file?

Tags: import, 3d-printing

I've imported some a model from an stl file. There are several "objects" (spatially separated), but Blender considers them as one object (due to the algorith of importing, I guess). Is there a simple way to separate those "objects" so that they become actually multiple Blender objects?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the object, enter edit mode with <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, select all with <kbd>A</kbd> and press <kbd>P</kbd> to separate, then choose whatever option suits your needs best. I am guessing you will probably want the *loose parts* one.