# degrouping stl file objects on blender

Tags: import, groups

I have imported an stl file to blender and its separate objects I can`t figure  out how to deselect the objects.

I have tried all the selection and deselection option
s 
The file was made on 123D
this is the STL file I imported to blender and I want to un-group the highlighted objects any suggestion thanks?

[image]

Comment: What is your question about ? Please elaborate on "degrouping objects" and "separate objects"; also provide some screenshots of the problem, what tools you have already used and why they didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Check the update to the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting disconnected vertices in different objects](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55436/splitting-disconnected-vertices-in-different-objects) and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49554/is-it-possible-how-to-separate-several-objects-imported-from-an-stl-file

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Separate function](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/editing.html?highlight=separate#separate).

Enter **Edit Mode** (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)

Highlight (select) the object you are breaking apart, press space, type **"separate"** (or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>P</kbd>) then pick "Loose Parts" from the list of options.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

To help you select the parts, you can select one vertex of or the specific item you want to separtate and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to select all of the connected vertices. Then separate using <kbd>P</kbd>

A different way to select different parts is using Box select (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>