# Splitting disconnected vertices in different objects

Tags: modeling, mesh

I know I can use Ctrl+L to select vertices connected to a given one than P to separate selected vertices and move them in another object (as explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6185/26425) for example).

But, is there a shortcut to do this automagically when there is like one hundred *sub objects* that I would like to separate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In edit mode select all (<kbd>A</kbd>), press <kbd>P</kbd> to [separate](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/editing.html?highlight=separate#separate) and select "by loose parts".

[image]

Unconnected geometry will be separated into new objects.