# Make two objects out of two pieces separated by boolean difference modifier

Tags: modifiers

I applied a boolean difference modifier to a rectangular object that removed a middle portion of it and I ended um with two parts. But now I want to select just one of the parts but both parts are selected, as they are still the same object. How can I separate them apart?
Thanks in advance,
Pedro

[image: a sample image]

Comment: press p and use *separate by loose parts* , see http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6185/2816

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to Apply the boolean modifier (it's a button in the modifier panel), then use the Spacebar menu to find the Separate operator, and choose the "By loose parts" option.

Comment: Ho my stars! I lost an hour looking for it everywhere! Your solution works! Thanks!