# Problem When Using Cell Fracture on hollow shapes

Tags: modeling, particles, physics

I'm trying to make a building able to collapse. The building has an open interior as seen below
[image] 
However, after I use cell fracture, the cells look like this 
[image]
Additionally, all the cells connect at the center and after any change explode outwards, like this
[image]
I'm basically trying to make it so if something hits the building, only a single side will go down at a time, instead of the whole thing exploding.

Comment: Why don't you separate your mesh into separate meshes, one for each side?

Comment: How can I separate the mesh?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object