# Can't separate objects when importing shapefile with Blender GIS

Tags: modeling, add-on

Whenever I try to import a shapefile (group of buildings), I get an error message.

I tried separating the extruded shapefile by loose parts, but some groups of buildings remain linked, so when I apply a constraint it doesn't work how it should (buildings on top of a TIN).

Is there any other way to separate the objects so that they will be successfully on top of the topography?

`ERROR: TypeError: invalid id-property type NoneType not supported`

Comment: What is the error you get? Could you [edit] the question with these details?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting pieces of a mesh into a new object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object)