# Split object after Boolean - difference operation

Tags: edit-mode

I've created a cylinder which, after applying the "boolean - difference" operation with another object (which was an stl file), consists of 2 parts because the other object was through the entire cylinder. I'd now like to separate the cylinder in these 2 parts and delete one of them. I'm however failing in using any of the split operations (accessed through hitting "p" in edit mode).

Does anyone have any experience with this and could help me with this? My blender file containing the cylinder can be found here:

https://app.box.com/s/9d6z16wxw62et0s4kohrrwa5pa091f7s

Thanks!

Comment: Related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've tried those options, but the splitting "by loose parts" doesn't seem to do anything. When I choose split by "selected" while selecting the cylinder, the new object is the same as the old object.

Comment: Have you applied the Boolean modifier before?

Comment: Yes I did. After applying that Boolean modifier (difference) and hiding the original rotor geometry, I can see the "cut" in the cylindrical object.