# How to separate joined objects in Blender?

Tags: objects

I thought this would be a common question, but I can't find any answers to it past 2009 (The answers from then seem to be outdated, it tells me to do Ctrl+P but it opens up a tab called 'Set Parent To"?).

I joined three objects using Ctrl+J, how do I "un-join" these objects?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find any clear answers to this.
Thanks!

Comment: Ctrl+P is still the answer, but it has to be done once in Edit mode and with all vertices selected

Comment: @NicolaSap No, Ctrl+P is for making a vertex parent. The correct shortcut is P.

Comment: @RayMairlot oh, sorry, my bad.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object