# separate a model with shape keys (recalculate shape-key vertex indexes?)

Tags: shape-keys

From this [UE4-reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/81eel6/what_method_should_i_use_for_facial_animation/dvd7hlo/) , I got the idea of separating head/body for game performance while getting all the shape-key goodies from Manuel Bastioni.

However, is there a way to "cleanly" separate a model without damaging its shape-keys?

(i.e. re-calculate shape-key vertex indexes during separation?)

From what I've seen from some maya-unreal tutorial, messing with shape-key vertex order seems to have hideous effects...

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to bse. What have you tried so far? Duplicating the object and removing from each to separate?  Or simply using the separate operator?  Are there any issues with those approaches?

Comment: @batFINGER sorry none of those... I'm quite new to blender... (like 1~2 months into this) I'm already having a lot of troubles even though I'm just following tutorials... so currently I'm not very brave enough to do some explorations myself :(

Comment: [How to Seperate into parts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object)  Suggest use a copy of file _to fiddle around with_  Select the head verts and separate to a new object.  Report back, via [editing question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/102633/edit),  with any issues you have.