# How can I split a mesh?

Tags: edit-mode

I'm making a dog head and am trying to seperate where the mouth goes but can't figure it out. The entire head is solid. The part still needs to be connected to the head.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting pieces of a mesh into a new object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object)

Comment: no i want it to still be  in the same object just not connected

Comment: If Duarte's link doesn't provide the information you seek, maybe start adding [relevant information](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to your question? [Images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1081/23985), for example? You can use the [edit link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/134792/edit) below your question to add information. It's quite hard to read anything out of one sentence.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Animate?

Comment: im making a game an this is going to be in it, but yes i do animate sometimes

Comment: maybe what you want is the rip tool: select the edge loop, press V, select one of the part with L, if you move it you can see it is now separate

Comment: that is exactly what i needed, thanks moonboots!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the rip tool: Select the edge loop, press <kbd>V</kbd>, select one of the parts with <kbd>L</kbd>, if you move it you can see it is now a separate mesh (but still part of the same object, to make a new object with this part, press <kbd>P</kbd>).

[image]