# Split meshes into separate objects based on closeness to others

Tags: objects, particles

I can't share my files but I have a long river scene where I have placed various rocks and plants along the river edges for several miles. These meshes are all now in one object as a result of being converted from particles to meshes and finally to a single mesh.

What I'd like to do is split this one huge multimillion vertice object to smaller objects so that each object still contains meshes near itself. Like take a big grid and make all meshes in one square of the grid into its own object and split the big object into smaller ones like that.

Comment: To separate objects see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object. Note that operator doesn't have any information about how one mesh is far from another one, the closest is to separate by loose parts (which isn't always desirable). Quick way could be to select several meshes and separate them by selection

Comment: Separating by selection is super slow as blender really struggles with the vertice quantities. It takes like 5-10 minutes to separate a small selection. I was hoping there was some trick to make those hundred 10 minute operations maybe into one 20 minute one. The basic selection tools don't work and I knew them already before asking the question.