# Create new object from selected faces while retaining faces on old object

Tags: objects, faces

I have the following model:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is for each face create a new object.  I found out how to do that here, [Splitting pieces of a mesh into a new object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object)

The problem is, **that method removes the faces when I select them from the original object** (refer to my screen shots)

[image]

[image]

**How do I create a new object from the selected faces without taking them away from the other object?**

I am doing this because I need to make another part that fits into the main object for 3D printing later.

Comment: Can't you duplicate then separate by selection? This would create a new separate object.

Comment: funny you mention that, I literally just did that and it worked.  Weird that you have to do that though, but it works :).  Is there a better way then this? You could add that as an answer though if you want and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this .GIF:

[image]

1. Select faces
2. Shift-D then right click to duplicate
3. Press P to separate

Comment: Yup that is the answer for sure :), thanks for making the gif, this will help a lot of other users.

Comment: How did you put the key- and mousestrokes into the GIF, by the way ? Is there a dedicated program ? Or did you put them in manually ?