# Does anyone know how to unattach the plane from the donut

Tags: modeling

[image]

For some reason they are stuck together. When I move the donut, the plane follows. I just got done parenting the icing to the bun, but I don't think its from that since it was doing that before hand.

Comment: it can be because you've enabled the Proportional Editing option (on the header menu, small sphere icon, it will be blue if enabled)

Comment: Are the donut and the plane separate objects, or is the plane part of the donut object? In the latter case, you can find the solution here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object

Comment: mine too, i go to edit mode and delete the vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Either, the plane is parented to the donut, which you can clear by selecting the plane and pressing alt+p to remove any parents, OR You accidentally joined them in the process, in which case you can select the donut, enter edit mode, select the plane's vertices, Click p and separate by an appropriate option e.g. selection, material or **loose parts** if it's been combined.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my solutions!

**Solution 1: If the Meshes Are Part of the Same Object**

[image]

You might have either accidentally joined both meshes ( control + J ). Or you added both objects in edit mode ( the donut and plane ) then they will be in the same object in object mode.

If that is the case I would enter edit mode.

[image]

To separate these meshes, you can press the vertice or face of one of the objects in edit mode and press the ( L-key ). This selects all the vertices of that mesh and you can delete that mesh.

[image]

Then right-click the selection and scroll down to "separate" and press "selection".

[image]

This will make your meshes two distinct objects again.