# Two objects don't separate

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I add this plane, and when I move it, the donut and plane move together.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting pieces of a mesh into a new object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object)

Comment: no because it's not a mesh you know...

Comment: Hi, please don't add solved to the title of questions (this is no forum), answering is sufficient, and users will know if a question is "solved".  You will soon be able to accept your self-answer also.

Comment: hi, how can I post another question? is too dificult to use this forum if I have to wait one hour to make the question.... Thanks

Comment: Hey @Pep, as a newer user there are some limitations, but over some time those start decrease as you contribute more good content and earn rep points. Check out the [tour] , there's some useful info there about how the site works and how it is different from the usual forum (it isn't one in the traditional sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved. You must click on proportional editing objects