# Change model to separated parts that can be seen in usdz

Tags: mesh, objects, export, parent, file-format

I described what I want to to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68404663/realitykit-hiding-and-showing-parts-meshes-of-usdz-model). I found out that usdz files (used in iOS RealityKit) can have "children" (different parts of model). I am using [this extension](https://github.com/robmcrosby/BlenderUSDZ) to export my model to usdz but it has only one children. How can I fix it? What should I set in Blender to have separated parts? I am iOS developer and I am new to Blender so I don't what are collections or what hierarchy should I use. Could someone help me?

This is how my current hierarchy looks in Blender:
[image: hierarchy from Blender]

Comment: What you see is what you get. Right now it's just one mesh object and (nothing to "fix"). Please specify *how* you would like to split it. By material? Frequently asked question by the way: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object

Answer (score 1):

with your object selected you can press "TAB" to go to edit mode. Then it looks like this:

[image]

If you then right click on your model, then a menu pops up and there is a "seperate"

[image]

As you can see, you can seperate by loose parts (if you have some), by material or by selection.

I assume you use selection so just select "some" vertices - but you should press this button here:

[image]

that you get all vertices (also the hidden ones)

and after choosing "selection" you get:

[image]

2 objects.