# How to deconstruct a ready-made model to view the inside?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, knife-tool

okay, so i recently bought the transportation addon from here https://blendermarket.com/products/transportation and i realised it was intricately built.. to the point that the seats, entertainment system etc and even the engine was modelled:

[image]

Here is an image of how dense the mesh is:

[image]

The problem is, there is no ready made "door" or "hood" and the whole frame is one solid mesh.

My question is: what is the best workflow to "deconstruct" a dense model like shown so that i can make the doors and hood able to swing open and shut to see the intricacies inside? Or what is the least tedious method to split the door/hood from the rest of the metal frame?

Comment: you can select the faces and Y to seperate as a different mesh, or P to separate as a different object, or select an edge and V to rip

Comment: There is no way around splitting it up manually. Select one vert, hit L to get the connected components, hit P > Seperate by selection. OR seperate by material in the first place. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object

Comment: Are you sure the whole mesh has no loose parts? In Edit mode, hover the mouse over the door and press `L` to selected linked verts. If it only selects the door then it's a loose part and you can separate or animate it. I would be surprised one modeled the interior and engine and you cannot see it.