# How do I move certain vertices to another mesh?

Tags: mesh, vertices

In blender - I have a mesh finished, but I need to add a moving object, but I already made a mesh, and I need a hole EXACTLY the size too, so I need to get the vertices where I want the moving part to be, and turn it into it's own mesh that I can animate, kind of like adding a new object with the Add menu.

Edit: this was solved by Allen Simpson, Apparently I just have to press  <kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: Hello, what you mean exactly by turning some vertices into their own mesh?

Comment: @moonboots I updated the original post, it should be more clear now.

Comment: Do you mean duplicating the vertices and Separate By (P) -> Selection?

Comment: @Allen Simpson Yes!! Exactly! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I'll try to find a duplicate to link this to, I think your title is good for search results.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @DiamondUp Welcome to the site, this question was closed due to a lack of detail.  This isn't "bad" or a punishment or anything, in this case it's just been linked to a canonical answer.  Feel free to ask more questions, we're glad to have you here. https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour