# Splitting Mesh into disconnected parts

Tags: mesh, scripting

I have a mesh that consists of many different disconnected pieces (hundreds). Does anyone know of a good **automated** method to split 1 mesh into many pieces?

Of course I could go one-by-one separating out the pieces by

- selecting a vertex
- pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to extend the selection
- pressing <kbd>P</kbd> and select *Separate by Selection*

..But when you have many pieces (like I do) that becomes a lot of work.

So I'm looking for a script, or another way to automize the process. The rule should be to split simply when the vertices are not connected.

Comment: Have you seen all the solutions in the suggested duplicate?

Comment: Yes of course. This question is not about how to separate part of a mesh - that's pretty basic and I know how to do it. This question is about separating a mesh into many parts using some automated process like a script.

Not sure why you keep on rejecting the question.

Comment: But isn't that what *Separate by Loose Parts* does by default without any scripts?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Uh, yes, you are absolutely right. *Mesh > Separate > By Loose Parts* does exactly what is asked here: it separates the parts that are not connected to each other into single objects, so it is indeed a **Duplicate** of https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6185/145249.

Comment: @quellenform Huh.. I guess I should have read a bit better the solution provided in your link.

It appeared to me the question was just about how to separate from a mesh and I never read on to realize you can also separate by material or loose parts.

Thanks to you both. Now I know how to do it :)